# confusion_matrix() | ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multiclass-multioutput targets

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, confusion-matrix, multilabel-classification

Definitely has been asked before, but I've not been successful at analysing other posts' solutions for my own instance of this problem.

I have many classification models I want to compare using `confusion_matrix()`

```
matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred) # ERROR
```

```
>>> y_pred
[[2 2 2 ... 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 ... 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 ... 2 2 2]
 ...
 [3 3 2 ... 3 2 3]
 [2 2 2 ... 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 ... 3 3 3]]
```

```
>>> y_pred.shape
(500, 256)
```

```
>>> y_test
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
```

```
>>> y_test.shape
(500, )
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multiclass-multioutput targets
```

When `.flatten()` is performed on `y_pred` - i.e. 1D array (500 * 256 = 128000):

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [500, 128000]
```

Comment: y_pred should be 1d array for comparision

Comment: How did your y_pred came in 2d array? what preprocessing have you done in y?

Comment: So I converted 'y_pred = model.predict(X_test_seq)' to be the same shape as 'X_test_seq'

Comment: 'y_pred' as a flattened array didn't work ;( @PrakashDahal

Comment: what is shape of `y_pred` after flattening?

Comment: @PrakashDahal (128000,)

Comment: can you tell me what does predicted `[2,2,2,2....2]` means? and what is your y?

Comment: @PrakashDahal. There are 3 classes to predict {1, 2, 3}. 'y' denotes labels in a dataset

Comment: The fact that you have 3 classes to predict does not justify a single prediction being an array of the form `[3 3 2 ... 3 2 3]` and length 256. Please **edit & update** your question to clarify and provide context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusion matrix works on the basis of comparision between each predicted value and actual value. It is impossible compare `1` with `[2,2,2....2,2,2]`

In your case, your y_pred is 2d but your y_test is 1d, thats where the actual error came. I believe that you have to choose the most common number in your predicted list. Like `2` from `[2,2,2....2,2]`

So here is the solution:

```py
from scipy import stats 
import numpy as np

#taking the most frequent element from the predicted list
y_pred_list = [int(stats.mode(arr)[0]) for arr in y_pred.tolist()] #convert to list

y_pred_array = np.array(y_pred_list)  #convert to 1D with same shape of y_test

print(y_pred_array.shape)

print(y_pred_array)

matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_array)
```